# How to delete just one type of entity on the ground

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How can I delete just one type of entity from the ground? I am only killing creepers using the `/kill @e[type=creeper]` command in a repeating command block, but it litters the ground with gunpowder. I want to delete only gunpowder from the ground but not any other ground item. Ideas?

I'm using Minecraft 1.12.2.

Comment: You can tag based on NBT and kill based on tag.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using [scoreboard tags](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard#Tags).  You can tag the items that have the specific NBT you want to select and then kill all entities with that tag.

This will use two command blocks in a chain.

Tag the items with a <kbd>Repeat</kbd> <kbd>Unconditional</kbd> <kbd>Always active</kbd> command block with command:

```
scoreboard players tag @e[type=Item] add Items {Item:{id:"minecraft:gunpowder"}}
```

Kill the items with a <kbd>Chain</kbd> <kbd>Conditional</kbd> <kbd>Always active</kbd> command block with command:

```
/kill @e[tag=Items]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler version. It takes a few ticks but it doesn't bear any side effects like `/kill` has.

`/tp @e[type=Creeper] ~ -1 ~`

Credit to [sumurai8's post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272147/how-do-i-kill-mobs-using-kill-without-them-dropping-loot/272176#272176) for mentioning this brilliant idea.