# How to kill all Items except for ones that players drop

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So to give you some background on what I'm trying to do, I've set up a safe-zone around world spawn where command blocks are used to kill entities that come within range. However, this generates a lot of mob drops which causes a lot of lag. So basically I would like to kill off all mob drops but not kill the dropped items from a player. 
I tried to use something like: 
/kill @e[type=item,nbt={Age:1200}]
set as a repeat non-conditional always active command block but it did not work to remove any items that had aged to 1 min. I'm not sure what to try next. Suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I kill mobs using /kill without them dropping loot?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272147/how-do-i-kill-mobs-using-kill-without-them-dropping-loot)

Comment: Yet another XY problem ...

Comment: @pppery To be fair, I think I have only heard that phrase once or twice on my entire time on gamingSE (other sites are a different story).

Comment: Though not quite the exact answer I was looking for, that article did allow for an alternative answer. If I were to want the mob items to drop and stick around for exactly the one minute but not affect the player drops then this answer would not be sufficient. But I think that would be dealing with loot tables... Oh well! All's well that ends well.